# How to push 2 navigation Link unto the stack in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

```swift
NavigationView {
   NavigationLink(destination: Text("1")) {
      Text("Click here")
   }
}
```

This pushed one view unto the stack when clicked. There will be a back button on the new screen to get back to the root view.

How do i push 2 views unto the stack so that it will be two levels deep instead of 1?
With two levels deep, I will have to press the back button twice in order to get back to the root view.

[Edit] - All the methods i have tried so far has the ugly animation of 2 Views literally being pushed to the screen.

Comment: NavigationView does not have such feature for now (SwiftUI 2.0)

Comment: no work arounds huh. Ok thanks. I'll proceed another way

Comment: @Justacoder did you manage to achieve this?

Comment: @unknown unfortunately i dont remember. But im thinking its a no.

Comment: Possible solution is implementing TabView